# How to Update a list with another list efficiently C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, big-o

I have two lists that have object elements, one big list let's call it List1 and another small list List2.
I need to update values in List1 with values in List2 based on a condition that is defined in a function that returns a boolean based on the values in the objects.
I have come up with the following implementation which is really taking a lot of time for larger lists.

**function to check whether an item will be updated**

```
private static bool CheckMatch(Item item1, Item item2) { 
//do some stuff here and return a boolean
}
```

**query I'm using to update the items**

In the snippet below, I need to update List1(larger list) with some values in List2(small list)

```
    foreach(var item1 in List1)
    {
        var matchingItems = List2.Where(item2 => CheckMatch(item1, item2));
        if (matchingItems.Any())
        {
            item1.IsExclude = matchingItems.First().IsExcluded;
            item1.IsInclude = matchingItems.First().IsIncluded;
            item1.Category = matchingItems.First().Category;
        }
    }
```

I'm hoping I will get a solution that is much better than this. I also need to maintain the position of elements in List1

Here is sample of what I'm doing
[Here is sample of what I'm doing](https://repl.it/repls/SimplisticIdenticalCensorware)

Comment: A lot of it comes down to facts about the matching. Suppose you have a million items in `List1` and a thousand in `List2`.  How many elements in `List1` get any match, on average? And of all those matches, how many were matches to *the same* object in `List2`?  That is, does every item in `List1` that matches have a *mostly unique* match in `List2`, or is there one element in `List2` that matches almost everything, or what?

Comment: If you can show us the _actual_ code for `CheckMatch` it opens up opportunities for optimisations that aren't available otherwise.

Comment: There really not much can be done to make it better than O(len(List1) * len(List2)) for general case... If you can some way for items to properly implement `IEqualityComparer<Item>` (with correct `GetHashCode` so dictionary can be used) than you get to O(len(List1) + len(List2))

Answer (score 9):

As LP13's answer points out, you're doing a large amount of re-computation by re-executing a query instead of executing it once and caching the result.

But the larger problem here is that if you have `n` items in `List1` and `m` potential matches in `List2`, and you are looking for *any* match, then worst case you will definitely do `n * m` matches. If `n` and `m` are large, their product is rather larger. And since we're looking for *any* match, the worst case is when there is no match; you'll definitely try all `m` possibilities.

Is this cost avoidable? Maybe, but only if we know some *trick* to take advantage of, and you've made the problem so abstract -- we have two lists and a relation, and no information about either the lists or the relation -- that there is no structure that we can take advantage of.

That said: if you happen to know that there is an element in `List2` that is likely to match *many* items in `List1` then put that element *first*.  `Any`, or `FirstOrDefault`, will stop executing the `Where` query after getting the first match, so you can turn an `O(n * m)` problem into an `O(n)` problem.

Without knowing more about what the relation is, it's hard to say how to improve the performance.

UPDATE: A commenter points out that we can do better if we know that the relation is an equivalence relation. Is it an equivalence relation?  That is, suppose we have your method that checks two items. Are we guaranteed the following?

- The relation is reflexive: `CheckMatch(a, a)` is always true.
- The relation is symmetric: `CheckMatch(a, b)` is always the same as `CheckMatch(b, a)`
- The relation is transitive: if `CheckMatch(a, b)` is true and `CheckMatch(b, c)` is true then `CheckMatch(a, c)` is always true

If we have those three conditions then you can do considerably better. Such a relation partitions elements into *equivalence classes*. What you do is associate each item in `List1` and `List2` with a *canonical value*. That canonical value is the same for every member of the equivalence class. From that dictionary you can then do fast lookups and solve your problem quickly.

But if your relation is not an equivalence relation, this does not work.

Comment: You probably should mention that proper `IEqualityComparer` will provide O(n+m) solution rather than O(n) in best case with moving best match forward.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Right, that's what I'm getting at when I say that we need to know more about the relation. It might not be an equivalence relation! But you're right that this should be called out more explicitly.

Comment: @EricLippert my data has no equivalence relation, please check for the updated question for the link to the sample code.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this? When you do only `.Where` it produces `IEnumerable` and then you are doing `First()` and `Any()` on IEnumerable

```
foreach(var item1 in List1)
{
    var matchingItem = List2.Where(item2 => CheckMatch(item1, item2)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (matchingItem != null)
    {
        item1.IsExclude = matchingItem.IsExcluded;
        item1.IsInclude = matchingItem.IsIncluded;
        item1.Category = matchingItem.Category;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically you can replace `Where` with `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: matchingItem is a list of objects that are the same, that's why I'm taking the first one

Comment: To clarify this (good) answer: **a query is not an answer, it is a question**. Every time you say `First` or `Any` on `matchingItems`, *the query starts over because LINQ thinks the answer might be different this time*.  This solution caches the answer and so only runs the query *once*.